# Image Importing & Painting in Android Java

Tags: java, android, image, paint

Recently, I have taken java and now am heading into Android Java.
However, Android has quite a few different things to tackle when programming.
So as my title says, how can I Import an image from my /res folder and paint it on the screen?

Usually, I would do something like this.

```
import java.awt.*
```

And in main class

```
public Image img;
```

And in public void paint

```
case CASE:
g2d.drawimage(...)
break
```

This doesn't seem to work in android.
Can someone explain how you could import and display images in a location in android?

Comment: you don't import. ImageView iv=(ImageView)findViewViewById(R.id.imageview);iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);. Example @ http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-imageview-example/

Comment: see this answer may help to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8047914/how-to-paint-on-image-and-save-that-image-in-to-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's great to see someone new trying out android development.

As for your question you could use and ImageView though if you are looking for something more dynamic then you should use a canvas. It will allowing for drawing images and animations.

I highly recommend you check out these tutorials:

Here is a list of 200 android tutorials that really helped me start out. Though some go over features that are now deprecated.
[Android Tutorials](http://thenewboston.org/list.php?cat=6)

Here is where the videos start going over basic game making. It goes from video #61 to about #80.
[Android Tutorial #61](http://thenewboston.org/watch.php?cat=6&number=61)

These videos can help you draw a basic image or make a simple game if that's what your looking for. Though I recommend you go learn as much of the basics as you can before going into anything really complicated.

Don't overextend yourself with something to difficult to begin with because it migh leave your frustrated with the entire android concept.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the list of tutorials and the advice. That really helped.

Answer (score 0):

u can add images/picture in the res/drawables

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html

Also different devices use different resolutions

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 0):

use a ImageView widget to display the image

```
image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
image.setImageResource(R.drawable.android);
```

this is assuming you have a file name android.png|jpg|gif etc in your drawable folder. If you want to use a image that is selected at runtime check here. [How to set the image from drawable dynamically in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11737607/how-to-set-the-image-from-drawable-dynamically-in-android)